# How can I use the recursion formula to get a power without it giving me segmentation fault?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I'm working on a lab for my C class and we are doing recursions and functions. I was looking for help and tried doing this that should get me the answer but when I type in my inputs, it only returns a segmentation fault.

I've tried rearranging the positions of the variables and functions and even the int/float types, but nothing seems to work and I always get the same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float power(float, int);

int main(void)
{
    float n;
    int k;

    printf("Please enter n = ");
    scanf("%f", &n);
    printf("Please enter k = ");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    printf("Sum = %f", power(n, k));

    return 0;
}

float power(float n, int k)
{
    return n * power(n, k - 1);
}
```

I expected 3 ** 3 is 27 but instead get Segmentation Fault :(

Comment: By stopping the recursion at the base case. It's infinite now - well, until stack overflow.

Comment: Do you mean I should add a if else loop for my power function? I don't quite follow.

Comment: No, an `if`. You can't add an `else` without there being an `if`. It can be hard to get your head around recusion, but think about what is happening. Why should the function not keep calling itself for ever?

Comment: If you don't know what a "base case" is, consider: is there a power `k` for which you always know the answer for all positive values of `n`?  In that case, just return the known answer.  That requires an `if`, no looping.

Comment: Ok that makes sense! I added the if and things are working now. Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your recursion is calling itself infinitely - it does `power(3, 3)`, `power(3, 2)`, `power(3, 1)`, `power(3, 0)`, `power(3, -1)`... and so on.

Any number to the power of 0 is 1.0 - that's your base case, so that's where you return.

For a bit of error catching, you can also see if the power passed in is too small to be valid.

```c
float power(float n, int k)
{
    if(k > 0) {
        return n * power(n, k - 1);
    }
    if(k == 0) {
        return 1.0;
    }
    return 1.0 / power(n, -k);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me! I just added an extra scenario with if (k == 0){return 0;}

Comment: @TreausreDragon That's not the correct answer for `k== 0`.

Comment: I checked and it actually did work this way. I plugged in numbers from the homework and I got expected outputs. Oh wait I see what you mean. I put return 1 not 0 oops

Comment: For large `k`, will certainly cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to admit that recursion is wrong and broken, and should never be used.

For example, if you add something to stop the recursion (e.g. `if(k == 0) return 1;`) **it will still cause segmentation faults for large values of `k`** (e.g. if you do `x = power(1.0, INT_MAX)`).

For this case, it's trivial to convert it into a simple loop; like:

```
    float power(float n, int k) {
        float result = 1.0;
        while(k > 0) {
            result *= n;
            k--;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

However even though this is no longer horribly bad because of recursion, it's still not good because the algorithm is inefficient (especially for large values of `k`).

A more efficient algorithm is something like:

```
    float power(float n, unsigned int k) {
        float result = 1.0;
        while(k > 0) {
            if( (k & 1) != 0) {
                result *= n;
            }
            k >>= 1;
            n *= n;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

For this version, with a large value of `k` like 50000 the loop will only be executed 16 times instead of 49999 times, which makes it significantly faster.

Of course you can make the efficient version bad again by using recursion, like this:

```
    float power(float n, unsigned int k) {
        float result = 1.0;

         if(k > 1) {
             result = power(n*n, k >> 1);
         }
         if( (k & 1) != 0) {
            result *= n;
         }
         return result;
    }
```

In this case, (instead of being significantly more efficient because it loops a lot less) it will be significantly more efficient because it recurses a lot less (and then slightly less efficient because recursion sucks); and "recurses a lot less" is important because it means that it's far less likely that large values of `k` will make it crash.

Comment: "recursion is wrong and broken, and should never be used" is an over-statement.  Yet I agree that recursion is not needed for `power()`.

Comment: @chux: Yes, it's an over-statement (but under-statements get ignored and over-statements are far more effective at highlighting a point). ;-)

Comment: I emphatically absolutely positively disagree that over-statements are good - [wink wink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZW-AZ2mNeA) 